# How to pass 2D string array to powershell script?

Tags: arrays, powershell, command-line

Let's have PS `script` accepting single parameter `p` of `String[][]`. Is there a way, how to pass equivalent of `@(@(1,2), @(a,b))` natively on commandline (`cmd`) when calling powershell?

Something like:

```
powershell.exe -Command .\script -p "(1,2),(a,b)"
```

The only thing I managed to do is to pass `String[]` via `"1,2,a,b"`.

Comment: Don't use quotes around the whole parameter `-p` value because it will be interpreted as a string. Use `-p (1,2),(a,b)`. You can quote the individual elements inside if necessary. However, you should quote the `-Command` value --> `powershell.exe -Command ".\script -p (1,2),(a,b)"`. Are you running this from cmd shell or PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put double quotes around a parameter value even if it contains commas, that value will be interpreted as a string. If you want an array of strings, you can quote individual elements of each array to make them strings. Allow PowerShell to interpret the comma as an operator, and you will have success. You should also surround `PowerShell.exe`'s `-Command` value in double quotes whether calling in CMD shell or PowerShell.

For your example, use:

```
Powershell.exe -Command ".\script.ps1 -p (1,2),(a,b)"
```

For individual quoted elements, you can easily use single quotes, which will not require escaping:

```
Powershell.exe -Command ".\script.ps1 -p ('first','second','third'),('fourth','fifth','sixth')"
```

As an aside, you can technically use the array subexpression operator `@()` as well.

```
Powershell.exe -Command ".\script.ps1 -p @(@(1,2),@(a,b))"
```

---

**Inner Double Quoting Scenarios:**

- Inner double quotes will require escaping. The escape methods differ depending on the calling shell.
- CMD shell calls to external programs require backslash escaping `\` of inner quotes.
- PowerShell calls to external programs require backtick escaping first and then backslash escaping.
- An example using CMD:

  ```
  Powershell.exe -Command ".\script.ps1 -p (\"one\",\"two\"),(\"a\",\"b\")"
  ```
- An example using PowerShell:

  ```
  Powershell.exe -Command ".\script.ps1 -p (\`"one\`",\`"two\`"),(\`"a\`",\`"b\`")"
  ```

---

[About_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6) describes the comma operator. As a binary or unary operator, it creates an array. If the value (object) containing the comma is surrounded by quotes, it will be a `[string]` rather than `[object[]]` because the comma is considered part of the value rather than a separator or operator.

Comment: Cool, thanks, so the key is right quoting and understanding `,` as an operator.